# Xamarin Tasky sample deployment failed

Tags: xamarin

I am trying to run Tasky sample from Xamarin for Android emulator, using VS2013.

It gives the deployment failed error at the end. How to know what caused it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these suggestions

[Unable to run Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27790785/)

Check out the logs section to see what the actual error is.