# On opening a tabbed page for the first time, images in listview of content page not loading

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

I don't know if anyone else has experienced this, i've been looking for examples left, right and centre to no avail.

Anyway, i'm developing an app using Xamarin forms for ios, android and windows phone. The first page of the app is a tabbed page and the first content page consists of a listview with an image (with the source bound to a string with a url) and some labels. I get the data via binding and everything loads correctly except the images. However, when i open a new page and then go back to the tabbed page, the images suddenly appear. I'm testing on a Windows Phone 8.1 at the moment.

Anybody else experienced this? Any work arounds? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This might be caused by a known issue that was fixed in 2.2.0-pre1

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=39447

Try updating to that pre-release version and seeing if it resolves your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Updated to v 2.2.0.4-pre1 but still the same issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Tried on an android device today but got this error: Android application is debugging.
The application could not be started. Ensure that the application has been installed to the target device and has a launchable activity (MainLauncher = true).

Additionally, check Build->Configuration Manager to ensure this project is set to Deploy for this configuration.
Been looking around how to fix that but no luck so far, sigh

Comment: Have a check of some of these solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27790785/unable-to-run-android-emulator

Comment: And also just to make sure you have the error messages sorted, in your MainActivity.cs you have MainLauncher=true in the class attribute? And also if you go to ConfigurationManger, the Android project has Build and Deploy both checked

Comment: Managed to test  my code on the android emulator and it works with no problem. Must be a bug on the Windows Phone side of things unfortunately.

Comment: Just to confirm, do the images show if you rotate the device on Windows?