# Xamarin.Android emulator. Couldn't connect to logcat

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2013, xamarin.android, windows-8.1, android-logcat

I can't test my app on emulator because after debug Visual Studio 2013 Community shows me a message:

> Couldn't connect to logcat. GetProcessId returned 0

All solutions like uncheck Fast Deployment, clean and rebuild solution, manifest manipulations don't help me. I am using VS2013 Community, Win 8.1.

Comment: [Is `adb` working](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting)?

   What is the output of `adb devices` command?

Perhaps you need to restart the `adb` daemon?

Comment: Is it by adb kill-server and then adb start-server in adb command prompt?

Comment: Yes, that's the command

Comment: Yes. Tried that several times( One more info: i'm using standart AVD -  Android_Accelerated_x86 (Android 6.0 - API 23)

Comment: Does `adb logcat` command work? There are couple of other options discussed on this post http://stackoverflow.com/q/36914487/85606

Comment: Yes, command prompt works and responces to commands such as 'adb devices', 'adb start/kill-server'. But even re-install Xamarin does not helps ( @PrashantC

Comment: There are multiple solutions given on xamarin forum and different worked for different people. check this link: [link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2274/message-couldnt-connect-to-logcat-getprocessid-returned-0)

For me, restarting adb server worked (tools -> android -> restart adb server)

Answer (score 1):

You can try any of below solutions for this situation.

1) Uninstall Mono Shared Runtime application from your device as well as application package

2) Turn off fast deployment form Android Options

3) Restart Adb Server

Answer (score 0):

In my case I figured it out that somehow (probably by mistake while in Project Properties -> Android Manifest) my:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
```

ended up being

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
```

Changed it back, fixed the issue for me.

None of the others fixed it for me.

An indication would be that if your project worked before and suddenly stop working, it might worth having a look.
Hopefully, this helps others as took me one hour to figure it out...